# How to Specify Tab in the Excel Document

Tags: excel, vba

Goal:
Tab named "bbb" should use the sourcecode below.

Problem:
In my excel document, I have nine tab and and one of them named "bbb" should be use the source code below. The question is how?

```
Sub sample()
 Range("B4:E7") = [index(upper(B4:E7),)]
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Worksheets("bbb").Range("B4:E7") = ...
```